# Why is there no existing tag for Daydream VR?

Tags: feature-request

There is a [daydream](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daydream) tag that actually pertains to the 2012 screensaver technology. It seems to have been misused in one question [Is there a way to increase fonts in google VR/Daydream?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164581/is-there-a-way-to-increase-fonts-in-google-vr-daydream) which is actually for the VR tech, which probably should have a separate [daydream-vr](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daydream-vr) tag.

I also wanted to use this tag for my question, but without 300 rep I can't create it. Hoping someone with tag privs agrees that it is useful and creates one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, simply looks like there was not demand from anyone who had the rep to make it!  I've retagged that question, and added the tag to yours.

Comment: Maybe you should edit the question and add [meta-tag:status-completed]?